# Magento - Add custom option label next to price

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We're running Magento 1.7.0.2 and need to do the following

We have products that we sell in different packs, which we have added as a custom option for each product.

For example:
Product XYZ has a custom option of "Pack Size" and the options are:
2 Pack - $2.99 (base price)
6 Pack - $10.99
12 Pack - $20.99

On the font end when the radio button for each pack is selected the price changes (which is correct), but with the price we would also like to add the label next to it.

so instead of just showing the price a:
$2.99
$10.99
$20.99

it would be:
$2.99 / 2 Pack
$10.99 / 6 Pack
$20.99 / 12 Pack

We would greatly appreciate any help or if you can just point us in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For that check `{$theme}/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml` and `{$theme}/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml`.. try using like `$this->getLabel()` to get the label.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to chnage method getJsonConfig() in Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options.php. Need add label info for  object  var opConfig = new Product.Options() in base\default\template\catalog\product\view\options.phtml/. And then add it in this file js\varien\product.js near reload method.

Comment: Hi Valianstin, I think you're on the right track with editing the product.js file, I just don't know what exactly needs to be edited. Also, I might have not explained my self correctly. I found the following topic that is exactly what I need, but the solution is not posted. - http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/694302/